# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier causes blank table cell

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

My goal is to display a list of cells that are populated by some data I pull down from a server. And as the user scrolls down I would like there to be, briefly, a table cell that says "Loading More", and then goes away as more cells are filled in with data.

Here are the relevant sections to do this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   [tableView registerClass:[CGSitesCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   // Option 1:   CGSitesCell *cell = [[CGSitesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   // Option 2:   CGSitesCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   //(Still Option 2):  
   //if(cell == nil){
   //      cell = [[CGSitesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
   if(backupsArray.count !=0){
       //if we not on the last row
      if (indexPath.row < backupsArray.count) {
             [cell.textLabel setText:someData];
      }else{
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       [cell.textLabel setText:@"Load More"];
       return cell;
      }
   return cell;
 }
```

Here is what has me stumped: Option 1 works. I see the data I want to see and the Load More at the bottom. However, Option 2 does not work! I see the data, but I only see a BLANK table cell. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Using storyboard? Have you specified the identifier  of the prototype cell?

Comment: Not sure whether your code is correct with all the comments above, especially the omission of your cellIdentifier initialization. For option 2, you can try (CGSitesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier] instead of [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath] which is for iOS 6.0 and above. Just guessing since I don't know which iOS you're testing on.

Comment: @verbumdei no storyboard.

Comment: @Rick The comments are just a way of (hopefully) making it easy to see what the different options are.

Comment: @Rick do you know why this would make a difference? it does. i'm testing it out on ios 6.1

Comment: It makes a difference only if your app supports iOS below 6.0 because XCode will not tell you there is an error. For iOS 6.0, it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I came cross you question and dont know if you found the problem, but if you custom cell is built with Interface Builder then you should register the Nib, not the class:

```
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CGSitesCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CGSitesCellIdentifier"];
```

And please do it in ViewDidLoad, not in cellForRowAtIndexPath which is called for all your cells :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by making the "Load More" as a `UIView` and setting it as the `UITableView` footer view instead of making it a table cell and then only making it visible when the last row of the table is visible using

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [backupsArray count] - 1) {

```
       //load more records here

    }
```

}`

I also had to set a `BOOL` instance variable to keep track of when I was loading more because this method gets called multiple times the last cell is visible and I don't want to load more records repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks! But one of the reasons I asked my question was to figure out what is going on with my code regardless of whether or not there is another, even better, way of doing things.