# Why is my UIViewController not showing up in my popup card?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I wanted to create a pop up for one of my ***UIViewController*** and found this [repo](https://github.com/SteveBarnegren/SBCardPopup) on GitHub.

It is working fine with my ***InfoViewController*** which only has 4 ***UILabels*** (I think this might be the problem that it is not showing up when you use reusable cells)
But somehow it is not working with my ***StructureNavigationListViewController*** and I do not know why.

I call the ***didTapCategory*** method in my ***MainViewController*** where the StructureNavigationController should pop up but I only see the dimming view (which is weird cause the tap recognizer and pan gestures are working fine but no content is showing up)

---

In my ***MainViewController*** I set up the popup like before:

```
    @IBAction func didTapCategory(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let popupContent = StructureNavigationListViewController.create()
        let cardpopUp = SBCardPopupViewController(contentViewController: popupContent)
        cardpopUp.show(onViewController: self)
    }
```

---

In my ***StructureNavigationListViewController*** I set up the table view and the pop up:

```
public var popupViewController: SBCardPopupViewController?

    public var allowsTapToDismissPopupCard: Bool = true

    public var allowsSwipeToDismissPopupCard: Bool = true

    static func create() -> UIViewController {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StructureNavigationListViewController") as! StructureNavigationListViewController
        return vc
    }

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var structures = Variable<[Structure]>([])
    public var treeSource: StructureTreeSource?
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    var depthDictionary : [String : Int] = [:]

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        structures.asObservable()
            .bind(to:tableView.rx.items) {(tableView, row, structure) in
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StructureNavigationCell", for: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as! StructureNavigationCell
                cell.structureLabel.text = structure.name
                cell.spacingViewWidthConstraint.constant = 20 * CGFloat(self.depthDictionary[structure.id]!)
                return cell
            }.disposed(by:disposeBag)

        _ = tableView.rx.modelSelected(Structure.self).subscribe(onNext: { structure in
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
            let plansViewCtrl = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PlansViewController2") as! PlansViewController2
            self.treeSource?.select(structure)
            plansViewCtrl.treeSource = self.treeSource
            plansViewCtrl.navigationItem.title = structure.name
            self.show(plansViewCtrl, sender: self)
            if let mainVC = self.parent as? ProjectOverViewTabController2 {
                mainVC.addChildView(viewController: plansViewCtrl, in: mainVC.scrollView)
            }
        })
        showList()
    }
func showList() {
        if treeSource == nil {
            treeSource = StructureTreeSource(projectId:GlobalState.selectedProjectId!)
        }

        //The following piece of code achieves the correct order of structures and their substructures.
        //It is extremely bad designed and rather expensive with lots of structures and should
        //therefore be refactored!
        if let strctrs = getStructures() {
            var sortedStructures : [Structure] = []
            while(sortedStructures.count != strctrs.count) {
                for strct in strctrs {
                    if let _ = sortedStructures.index(of: strct) {
                        continue
                    } else {
                        depthDictionary[strct.id] = getDepthOfNode(structure: strct, depth: 1)
                        if let structures = getStructures() {
                            if let parent = structures.first(where: {$0.id == strct.parentId}) {
                                if let index = sortedStructures.index(of: parent) {
                                    sortedStructures.insert(strct, at: index+1)
                                }
                            } else {
                                sortedStructures.insert(strct, at: 0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            structures.value = sortedStructures

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func getDepthOfNode(structure: Structure, depth: Int) -> Int {
        if(structure.parentId == nil || structure.parentId == "") {
            return depth
        } else {
            if let structures = getStructures() {
                if let parent = structures.first(where: {$0.id == structure.parentId}) {
                    return getDepthOfNode(structure: parent, depth: depth + 1)
                }
            }
        }
        return -1
    }

    private func getStructures() -> Results<Structure>? {
        do {
            if let projectId = GlobalState.selectedProjectId {
                return try Structure.db.by(projectId: projectId)
            }
        } catch { Log.db.error(error: error) }

        return nil
    }
}
```

---

Lot of code here. Sorry..

Is it because I call the ***create()*** method after the ***viewDidLoad()*** dequeues the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what is the problem, since you left no information about where `didTapCategory` is supposed to be called, but maybe it has something to do with your `modelSelected` subscription being prematurely released?

**Edit:**
As posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896452/11851832 if your custom cell is built with Interface Builder then you should register the Nib, not the class:

```swift
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellIdentifier")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it is not working. I did the same thing but with no results. I call the ***didTapCategory*** method in my ***MainViewController*** where the ***StructureNavigationController*** should pop up but I only see the dimming view (which is weird cause the tap recognizer and pan gestures are working fine but no content is showing up)

Comment: Could you please make sure that Xcode is not reporting Runtime errors? Perhaps you call your didTapCategory on wrong thread - in such case you will see a runtime error report in your Issue Navigator.

Comment: No runtime errors. I created another Controller and call it the same way I do with didTapCategory. But I am not using cells to show the content but instead only 4 labels in the storyboard file and it is working.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28896452/11851832 ?

Comment: I assume that you find my last comment helpful? If yes, I would like to edit my original answer, so that other users could find it easily.